# Selecting the ETL tool

Tags: oracle, ssis, cassandra, etl

I will have this situation in my project:

DB: Cassandra

Data Source: A Relational DB

Manager of ETL process: .NET API

ETL TOOL: ???

[image]
I will use **Cassandra** as my database.
It will collaborate with **Oracle** db using an ETL tool, **dynamically**.
The source data has stored in oracle and it will use in Cassandra with the management of an **API**.

The question is that, what ETL tool is better in this situation, since my ETL manager, which will select the parameters **dynamically**, is a .NET API (User will use this API backstaires, using the project.)

SSIS was a good tool, since it's compatible with Microsoft .Net. but incompatible with Cassandra 3.x ). Then, we can't use the benefits of new versions of Cassandra, as materialized view, SASI secondary index (soon) and etc.

Comment: Without knowing what Cassandra is, i hit a similar issue when trying to use SSIS with Salesforce - there is no native connector.  I toyed with the idea of writing a custom one (painful!) but then found the CozyRoc components which are great.  I don't think they have a custom component for Cassandra but have you looked to see if somebody has created one?  I would always opt for SSIS as my first choice.

Comment: I didn't find popular and famous ETL tool in this situation, which guarantees compatibility with .net, and we can manage that externally, using a module or API or s. th. like that. It's important to use valid tools in my issue.

Comment: Hmm not sure i fully understand your question.  https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-drivers?dxt=DX here is an ODBC driver which will give you access to Cassandra DB.  However reading the comments posted its pretty basic.  Could you use SSIS with a script component and then interface the results into a WCF layer which could use the native C# drivers for Cassandra?  I have done this before with different DB, its slower but effective